# For my simple formula using ISNUMBER it is not rendering the value when true

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the following formula to try and render one date equation if the text word "Apple" is included in a corresponding cell, and another date equation if the word "Apple" is not in the corresponding cell. Regardless of whether the word Apple exists, the formula always renders the date for False. What am I doing wrong?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(“Apple”,A1)), EDATE(E1,2), EDATE(E1,1))
```

Comment: Are those double quotes really the same characters you're using in Excel? Excel formulae usually use plain double quotes `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula instead:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Apple",A1)), EDATE(E1,2), EDATE(E1,1))
```

The only difference is that `“` and `”` have been replaced with `"`. Excel doesn't recognise the 'fancy' double quotes and if you use the "Evaluate Formula" option to check each calculation step of the function, you will almost certainly see that `“Apple”` becomes `#NAME?`. This is an error and means that `ISNUMBER` also always gets an error, hence, always evaluating to the false part of the `IF`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. So, forgive my ignorance, but how can I create the non-fancy quotes? For this I copy and pasted your text and it worked, but how would I use my keyboard to create in the future? Thanks!

Comment: @Audra Excel shouldn't be using smart quotes (the official name of the fancy quotes). I know that MS Word does, so perhaps you're typing it from there or another application? If it's really MS Word, you can look into this [support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/206165).